# postgresql start db

Tags: postgresql, macports, osx-leopard

I have postgresql running (/opt/local/lib/postgresql90/bin).

The data base is set up @ /Users/demet8/postgres/data.

I check to make sure postgresql is running with

ps aux | grep postgres

demet8    9851   0.0  0.1   614276   1184   ??  Ss   12:40PM   0:00.24 postgres: autovacuum launcher process
demet8    9850   0.0  0.0   614020    436   ??  Ss   12:40PM   0:00.91 postgres: wal writer process
demet8    9849   0.0  0.0   614020    496   ??  Ss   12:40PM   0:01.22 postgres: writer process
demet8    9847   0.0  0.1   614020   2248 s002  S    12:40PM   0:00.61 /opt/local/lib/postgresql90/bin/postgres -D /Users/demet8/postgres/data
demet8   11127   0.0  0.0   599820    468 s002  S+    2:05PM   0:00.00 grep postgres
demet8    9852   0.0  0.0   610092    368   ??  Ss   12:40PM   0:00.26 postgres: stats collector process

I go back into: /opt/local/lib/postgresql90/bin & now try to start the db with ./pg_ctl start. This is the error msg I get:

pg_ctl: no database directory specified and environment variable PGDATA unset
Try "pg_ctl --help" for more information.

Any suggestions on to what I can be doing wrong. I googled around the web for answers & I haven't found a solution.

Comment: If it is already started why do you want to start it again?

Comment: I want to be able to enter the db once it's running. I used ./pg_ctl start a couple of times to get into the db & it worked. For some reason it doesn't work now. I also tried $su - then su -postgres & the db responds back with "sorry." I'll have to keep trying until I figure this thing out. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "to enter the db" and "to get into the db"?

Comment: If you want to start an interactive session then the command is `psql`

Comment: I wanted to get an interactive session going is what I was trying to explain & I should have clarified that better. I just figured it out. I entered ./psql postgres & it worked. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ su -
# su - postgres
```

Proceed from there.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is already answered but, if you are new to Postgres and seeing similar issues, try the below commands to resolve the **error pg_ctl: no database directory specified and environment variable PGDATA unset Try "pg_ctl --help" for more information.**

```
1. su - postgres
2. find / -name pg_ctl --> gives you the location where pg_ctl present, in my case it is there in `/usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/`
3. /usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/11/main
```